# Express js redirect for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, node.js, redirect, express

My question is: how can I redirect to another site if the browser is internet explorer when I am using a server created using express js? First, I need to know how to find out which browser I am in. BrowserDetect does not work in node js and then I would like to know how to redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ieRedirecter = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf("MSIE") >= 0)
    res.redirect("http://example.com/");
  else
    next();
};
```

You can use that either as an express middleware or in a route.

Answer (score 1):

Independently of Express.js, you can do all this client-side, with HTML tags and conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://getridofIE.com/">
<![endif]-->
```

There are other ways to detect the browser, using user-agent strings and such, but this one is pretty simple and effective. Other options, [from the mouth of Microsoft itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For completeness' sake, but useless in this solution, you can redirect in Express.js using `res.redirect('http://www.whatever.com');` (which will issue a response status of 302 by default, or you can specify one as 2nd argument).